# Playing array of audio in sequence not working even if I have ended function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to play all my audio files in sequence with the duration between each audio. Right now, I can play the first audio, but I have to click the play button again in order to play the second audio. ended function should handle this, shouldn't it? Appreciate your kindness and help.

```
var playList = [{
        "duration": 1000,
        "value": "0_silence"
    }, {
        "duration": 4000,
        "value": "1_hello"
    }, {
        "duration": 6000,
        "value": "2_how_old"
    }];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

        var i = 0;
        $("#play").on("click", function(){

            audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio(playList));
                function playAudio() {
                    if(i < playList.length) {
                        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound/' + playList[i].value + '.wav');

                        setTimeout(function (){audioElement.play(); playAudio, playList[i].duration;});

                        i++;
                    } else {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
        });

   //         playAudio(playList);
   //         });
   //                
   //         function playAudio() {
   //         var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
   //         audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio(playList));
   //         if (i < playList.length) {
   //                    
   //         var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
   //         audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio(playList));                   

   //         audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sound/' + playList[i].value + '.wav');
   //         audioElement.play();
   //         setTimeout(playAudio, playList[i].duration);
   //         i++;
   //         } else {
   //         i = 0; // reset i to zero to start over if button clicked again
   //         }
   //         }
}
```

Comment: You are listening to the onended of a single audio element, but creating multiple ones. Only the first will have this listener. To avoid that, you could always use the same audioElement. Also, dont attach event handlers in click events.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for replying. So you mean I shouldn't have a audio element outside click event? If so, my audioElement wouldn't be defined. Or you mean I should define the audioElement inside of click event? And I will have to attach event handlers.... so is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: Here you are creating multiple `<audio>` elements. One in the `ready` event (let's call it `ready_audio`), and new ones in the `ended` event (let's call these `ended_audio`). This ended event will only fire for `ready_audio`, because you did attach the event listener only to it. `ended_audio` doesn't have this event listener set up. But currently, `ready_audio` will play only once. So there will be only one `ended_audio` to be created, and nothing else will happen from your code. One easy solution is to only use `ready_audio`, and to update its own `src` in the `ended` event.

Comment: Also, this event should be attached out of the `click` handler, otherwise, you'll attach it at each click, and the code will execute more than once at each `ended` event.

Comment: Thank you for replying again James. I have updated my code but not much. You are right. I only need one audio element in ready_audio. Now it's working but it doesn't play the next audio. The ended function should handle this, shouldn't it? My code is updating each time when the audioElement plays, isn't it? Also, if I attach the event out of the click handler, the playAudio function wouldn't be defined... How should I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error is in this line:

```
audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio(playList));
```

Here the function `playAudio()` is called and the result from it (`undefined` in this case) is handed to the `addEventListener()` as argument, which of course won't work. If the `playList` is global simply change it to:

```
audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio);  // function is now referenced
```

In addition, the handler is called every time the play button is clicked. Only add it once when the element is created.

There is also an error in the `setTimeout()` call, as shown in the post, as it misses a time argument and contains invalid statements inside the function block.

However, it shouldn't be necessary to use this call as calling `play()` on the element will, in newer browsers, cue up the call. For older browsers you may need to use the `canplay` event. `setTimeout()` is not recommended here in either case.

You should also [call `load()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-load) before `play()` to reset and cleanup the element, and to start loading the new source.

And finally, if the intention is to play the list in a loop the list will fail when last track has been played as `i` is reset in a separate else-block which does not invoke play.

You might want to consider how the play button behaves in order to prevent it from loading samples while playing (ie. toggle pause/play). I wrapped up the fixes above except from the play-button (I rewired it to share the `playAudio()` function) here using random short samples:

```js
var playList = [{
  "duration": 1000,
  "value": "http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/SFX%20and%20UNUSUAL%20SOUNDS/ELECTRO%20and%20SYNTHETIC/257[kb]50s_space_telemetry.aif.mp3"
}, {
  "duration": 4000,
  "value": "http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/SFX%20and%20UNUSUAL%20SOUNDS/ELECTRO%20and%20SYNTHETIC/85[kb]analog_alarm_up.aif.mp3"
}, {
  "duration": 6000,
  "value": "http://sampleswap.org/samples-ghost/SFX%20and%20UNUSUAL%20SOUNDS/ELECTRO%20and%20SYNTHETIC/42[kb]alien_alarm.aif.mp3"
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
  
  // reference function instead of calling it. Also, only set it once.
  audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio); 
    
  var i = 0;
  $("#play").on("click", playAudio); // rewired to share playAudio()
  
  function playAudio() {
    var entry = playList[i++];       // get current entry, increment i
    if (i >= playList.length) i = 0; // if i=> length, reset

    audioElement.src = entry.value;  // <- for demo samples only. 'sound/' + entry.value + '.wav';
    audioElement.load();             // cleanup old fun, invoke loading of new
    audioElement.play();             // cue up play
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=play>Play</button>
```

Comment: `audioElement.load();` did everything work for me, thanks